# Axis2: Web service with Java collection framework not working

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have a web service that receives `List<String>` as input. But when I created a stub for testing this service stub contains the same element as `java.lang.String[]` type.

How can I effectively use java collection framework with axis2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its a known issue . Please check if this helps http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-coding/index.html

Comment: @user2506840 thank you. The information provided by you was useful. Some one needs more information, please go through this link http://www.coderanch.com/t/415647/Web-Services/java/Axis-support-collections